# Strange behaviour when trying to upload data to Spring MVC using XMLHttpRequest - Error 406 only in browser

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, upload, xmlhttprequest, http-error

I have a strange behaviour when I am trying to upload data to Spring MVC and download a file using Spring MVC.

This is the server side:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/generate",  consumes = {"multipart/form-data"},  produces = {"multipart/form-data"})
public ResponseEntity generate(@RequestParam final MultipartFile myMultipartFile)
{
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = null ;

    try
    {
        responseEntity = this.generateInternal(myMultipartFile) ;
    }
    catch (IOException ioException)
    {
        responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body(ioException.getMessage()) ;
    }

    return responseEntity ;
}
```

(1) On the other hand, the following code is working properly:

```
var input    = document.getElementById('myFile');
var xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest() ;   
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myMultipartFile", input.files[0]) ;

xhr.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/generate", true) ;
xhr.responseType    = "blob" ;
xhr.withCredentials = false ;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
       var blob = xhr.response;
       console.log("This code is working properly, I can download the file") ;
    }
};

xhr.send(formData) ;
```

(2) But...the following code is not working properly :(

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() ;

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myMultipartFile", "The content is a YAML") ;

xhr.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/generate", true) ;
xhr.responseType = "blob" ;
xhr.withCredentials = false ;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        var blob = xhr.response;
        console.log("This code is never executed, I got a 402 HTTP Error") ;
    }
};

xhr.send(formData) ;
```

In this second example (2), I got an error in the browser (406 (Not Acceptable)). If I add the dependency 'spring-boot-starter-actuator' in the Java project (to monitorize the requests - using "/trace"), I got the following response info:

```
response: {
X-Application-Context: "application",
status: "400"
}
```

The previous response is quite different than the correct response (1):

```
response: {
X-Application-Context: "application",
Content-Type: "multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8",
Transfer-Encoding: "chunked",
Date: "Mon, 20 Jun 2016 15:43:52 GMT",
status: "200"
}
```

The only difference between the (1) and (2) is the mechanism to send the file:

- (1) Sends via "File"
- (2) Sends via "String"

Has anyone had this strange behaviour? How did you resolve it?

Many thanks.

Regards,
Paco.